# How to search data from different tables on mysql(Xampp). I'm using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have 4 tables on my database mysql(Xampp),
tbl_classic,
tbl_signature,
tbl_fusion,
tbl_blends, each tables have 5 columns ID, FlavorItems, FlavorQuantity, MediumPrice, LargePrice. How to search the value of FlavorItems in all tables?

```vb
    Dim sql1 As String = ("Select * From tbl_classicmilktea where FlavorItems = @FlavorItems")

    cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql1, cn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FlavorItems", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtSearch.Text

    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)

    cn.Open()

    Dim table As New DataTable()

    Try
        adapter.Fill(table)

        If table.Rows.Count() > 0 Then
            ' Return only 1 row.
            txtNo.Text = table.Rows(0)(0).ToString()
            txtFlavorItems.Text = table.Rows(0)(1).ToString()
            dudQuantity.Text = table.Rows(0)(2).ToString()
            txtMedium.Text = table.Rows(0)(3).ToString()
            txtLarge.Text = table.Rows(0)(3).ToString()
        End If
    Catch Ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("NO Data Found")
    End Try

    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Check for UNION  where you can combine select statements and get a single result set.

Comment: Why do you need separate tables for each type of tea? Especially if they all have the same columns. Just add "type" as an extra column and move everything into one table. Your structure is denormalised. If you find yourself creating multiple tables with essentially the same structure then that's a sign that you're using a table to represent an attribute of an entity, and that you should just be using a column for that, in a single table. Each table should really represent an entirely different entity in your data model, not just one variation of the same thing.